# JNA and array of booleans in struct

Tags: java, c, arrays, struct, jna

I want to transfer an array of booleans with in a struct between java and a dll written in C.
The struct in C looks like:

```
struct Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect_ {
  real_T Constant_Value;              

  boolean_T Memory_X0;               
  boolean_T Logic_table[16];         

};
```

In java I  have defined the following class to access it:

```
public class VehicleModel {
        public interface CLibrary extends Library {
               public static class Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect_ extends Structure {
                      public static class ByReference extends Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect_ implements Structure.ByReference {}

                            public double   Constant_Value ;  
                            public boolean Memory_X0 ;        
                            public Pointer Logic_table ;           
                       }
          }
}
```

This part of the main where I want to give a value to the boolean array:

```
public class SpecificVehicle {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

              Vehicle vh = new Vehicle();
              vh. parameters .Constant_Value = -1.000000;
              vh. parameters .Memory_X0 = false;

              CLibrary.Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect_.ByReference ltref = new CLibrary.Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect_.ByReference();
              ltref.Logic_table =  new Memory(16*Native.getNativeSize(?????????)   ) ); //???
       }
}
```

The problem is I do not know how to fill (and read) the array of booleans, I found examples on http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/ for an array of strings and an array of doubles, but I do not know how to translate them, so they will work for an array of booleans.

Could somebody give a small example on how to access an array of booleans in a struct?

Thanks a lot,
Frank

Comment: How big is `boolean_T`?  Choose a Java type of the same size, and make a primitive array of that type in your `Structure`.  *Do not* allocate separate memory for the logic table, unless your native struct does the same.

Comment: the boolean_T is a byte in C, so I used bety in java and that works fine. What do you mean with: Do not allocate separate memory for the logic table, unless your native struct does the same.

Comment: Your native and Java structures do not match.  Your native definition puts the byte array in the same memory block as the `struct`, while your Java `Structure` points to a separate memory block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

```
static Pointer setbooleanArray(boolean [] input) {
    Pointer output = new Memory(input.length*Native.getNativeSize(Byte.TYPE));
    for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        output.setByte(i, (byte) (input[i] ? 1:0));
    };
    return output;
};
```

...

And here I fill the logical table:

```
boolean[]  Logic_tableSet = new boolean[]   { false, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, false };
vh.parameters.Logic_table = setbooleanArray(  Logic_tableSet);
```

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate mapping for the native struct

```
struct Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect_ {
    real_T Constant_Value;              

    boolean_T Memory_X0;               
    boolean_T Logic_table[16];         
};
```

would be

```
public class Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect extends Structure {
    public double Constant_Value;
    public byte Memory_X0;
    public byte[] Logic_table = new byte[16];
}
```

You are implying that instead your native struct is defined as the following:

```
struct Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect_ {
    real_T Constant_Value;              

    boolean_T Memory_X0;               
    boolean_T* Logic_table;
};
```

This represents a distinctly different memory layout than what you pose in your question, namely:

```
                with array         with pointer
               +----------------+ +----------------+
Constant_Value | 0x0000-0x0007  | | 0x0000-0x0007  |
               |                | |                |
               |                | |                |
               |                | |                |
               |                | |                |
               |                | |                |
               |                | |                |
               |                | |                |
               +----------------+ +----------------+
Memory_X0      | 0x0008         | | 0x0008         |
               +----------------+ +----------------+
Logic_table    | 0x0009-0x0018  | | 3 or 7 bytes   |
(array)        |                | | padding        |
               |                | |                |
               |                | +----------------+
               |                | | 0x000C-0x000F  | logic_table (pointer)
               |                | | or             |
               |                | | 0x0010-0x0018  |
               |                | |                |
               |                | +----------------+
               |                |
               |                | 
               |                | 
               |                | 
               |                |
               |                |
               |                | 
               |                | 
               +----------------+
```

The difference in length on the right hand side is whether your pointers are 32- or 64-bit in size.  The left side may or may not have padding preceding the byte array, depending on your compiler and settings.

What does `sizeof(Parameters_VE3_RSG_v19b_Protect_)` return?